# How to identify and separate specific strings inside a text file whilst in a while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Sorry about the title. I wasn't really sure how to word it.

My task is to write out a payslip and cheque for an employee where the data is taken from a text file. Tax is included.

There is a simple version which I have completed which only calculates the pay and tax of one employee as only one employees data is included in the text file.
It uses this text file:

```
1 Feb Jane Auckland BBPL 190.00
1 Feb Jane Auckland LF1 760.80   
1 Feb Jane Auckland BBPL 1260.51
```

As shown it has the Day, Month, First Name, Last Name, Bank, and Pay/Commission.

The function for reading the text file is as shown:

```
printf("\nPayroll File Process\n");

#define DIRECTORY "C:\\# School Units\\Introduction to Software Engineering (2015 S1)\\Assignment\\Text Files\\"

FILE *infile;
char fileName[512];
char fullFileName[512];

int dayNumber;
char monthText[16];
char firstName[32];
char lastName[32];
char planCode[8];
double income;

double totalIncome = 0.00;
double totalNetIncome = 0.00;

fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
printf("\nEnter Monthly File: ");
scanf_s("%s", fileName, 120);

strcpy_s(fullFileName, 512, DIRECTORY);
strcat_s(fullFileName, 512, fileName);

infile = fopen(fullFileName, "r");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    printf("\nError Opening File >> %s \n\n", fullFileName);
    return;
}
else
{
    printf("\nSuccessfully Opened File >> %s \n\n", fullFileName);
}

while (6 == fscanf_s(infile, "%d %s %s %s %s %lf", &dayNumber, monthText, 16, firstName, 32, lastName, 32, planCode, 8, &income))
{
    //calculateTax(totalIncome);

    //printf("Debug> %d:%s:%s:%s:%s:%8.2lf\n", dayNumber, monthText, firstName, lastName, planCode, income);

    totalNetIncome = totalNetIncome + income;
}
calculateTax(totalNetIncome);
totalIncome = totalNetIncome;
totalNetIncome = totalIncome - tax;

printf("Pay slip for %s %s from file %s\n", firstName, lastName, fileName);
printf("+-------------------------+\n");
printf("| Commission : $ %8.2lf |\n", totalIncome);
printf("| Tax        : $ %8.2lf |\n", tax);
printf("|              ---------- |\n");
printf("| Net Pay    : $ %8.2lf |\n", totalNetIncome);
printf("+-------------------------+\n");

printf("\nOFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK '%s'\n", planCode);
printf("Please pay %s %s an amount of $%.2lf\n", firstName, lastName, totalNetIncome);
printf("[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911");

fclose(infile);
_getch();
return 0;
```

The outcome from reading the previously mentioned text file through this function is:

```
Pay slip for Jane Auckland from file examplem2.txt
+-------------------------+
| Commission : $  2211.31 |
| Tax        : $   131.86 |
|              ---------- |
| Net Pay    : $  2079.45 |
+-------------------------+

OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
Please pay Jane Auckland an amount of $2079.45
[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911
```

Formatting is not final.

As you can see, it works perfectly as there is only one employee in the text file. However, with the given task of reading several employees pay in one text file it will simply acquire all pay, use the tax function, and then assign the last employees name on the list to the pay slip and cheque.

The tax function is as follows:

```
double centsPerDollar;
double initialTax;
double minimumTax;

income = round(income); //Rounds income to the nearest integer.

if (income >= 0 && income <= 1517) //First tax bracket.
{
    centsPerDollar = 0.00;
    initialTax = 0.00;
    minimumTax = 0.00;

    tax = 0.00;
    taxedIncome = income;
}
else if (income >= 1518 && income <= 3083) //Second tax bracket.
{
    centsPerDollar = 0.19;
    initialTax = 0.00;
    minimumTax = 1517.00;

    tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
    taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
}
else if (income >= 3084 && income <= 6667) //Third tax bracket.
{
    centsPerDollar = 0.325;
    initialTax = 298.00;
    minimumTax = 3083.00;

    tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
    taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
}
else if (income >= 6668 && income <= 15000) //Fourth tax bracket.
{
    centsPerDollar = 0.37;
    initialTax = 1462.00;
    minimumTax = 6667.00;

    tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
    taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
}
else if (income >= 15001) //Fifth tax bracket.
{
    centsPerDollar = 0.45;
    initialTax = 4546.00;
    minimumTax = 15000.00;

    tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
    taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
}
else { fprintf(stderr, "Must be a positive number."); } //Error check for negative numbers.
```

The more complicated text file is as follows:

```
1 Feb Jane Auckland LF1 190.21
2 Feb Jane Auckland BDHIWAY 390.62 
7 Feb Adeeva Sharif LSZ 2000.00
8 Feb Adeeva Sharif LF2 52.00
4 Feb Jane Auckland ILZERO 101.03 
9 Feb Jerome Velence ILFIVE 4110.00
```

As mentioned before and as seen above, you can see that there are multiple employees in one text file and some employees are split up by other employees like 'Jane Auckland' has one pay separated by 'Adeeva Sharif'.

What I need to have done is for a new payslip and cheque printed for each employee in the text file, so in this case 3 pay slips and 3 cheques will be printed out. Similar as shown below:

```
    Pay slip for Jane Auckland from file examplep1.txt
    +-------------------------+
    | Commission : $   681.86 |
    | Tax        : $     0.00 |
    |              ---------- |
    | Net Pay    : $   681.86 |
    +-------------------------+

    OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
    Please pay Jane Auckland an amount of $681.86
    [  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911

    Pay slip for Adeeva Sharif from file examplep1.txt
    +-------------------------+
    | Commission : $  2052.00 |
    | Tax        : $   101.65 |
    |              ---------- |
    | Net Pay    : $  1950.35 |
    +-------------------------+

    OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
    Please pay Adeeva Sharif an amount of $1950.35
    [  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911

    Pay slip for Jerome Velence from file examplep1.txt
    +-------------------------+
    | Commission : $  4110.00 |
    | Tax        : $   631.78 |
    |              ---------- |
    | Net Pay    : $  3478.23 |
    +-------------------------+

    OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
    Please pay Jane Auckland an amount of $3478.23
    [  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911
```

The bank names such as BBPL, BDHIWAY, LF2 etc, provide nothing important and is just fluff but will still be included in the text file.

Just a recap of what I need help with. I need a new pay slip and cheque printed out for each individual employee that is shown in the text file (employee names may change depending on the text file and the last name may be spelt wrong) and I need each commission and pay to be processed through the tax calculator function.

Sorry if it is long, it is the only way I could word it.

Thanks in advance.

My whole code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//Error checking function for income using doubles.
bool readAndValidateIncome(double* income)
{
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (scanf(" %lf", income) != 1.00)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Error checking function for int.
bool readAndValidateInput(int* input, int min, int max)
{
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (scanf(" %d", input) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (min == 0 && max == 0)
        return true;

    if (*input < min || *input > max)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input not in range.\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Global variables for calculateTax function.
double tax = 0.00;
double taxedIncome = 0.00;

//Equations for calculating tax and net pay.
double calculateTax(double income)
{
    double centsPerDollar;
    double initialTax;
    double minimumTax;

    income = round(income); //Rounds income to the nearest interger.

    if (income >= 0 && income <= 1517) //First tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.00;
        initialTax = 0.00;
        minimumTax = 0.00;

        tax = 0.00;
        taxedIncome = income;
    }
    else if (income >= 1518 && income <= 3083) //Second tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.19;
        initialTax = 0.00;
        minimumTax = 1517.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 3084 && income <= 6667) //Third tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.325;
        initialTax = 298.00;
        minimumTax = 3083.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 6668 && income <= 15000) //Fourth tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.37;
        initialTax = 1462.00;
        minimumTax = 6667.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 15001) //Fifth tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.45;
        initialTax = 4546.00;
        minimumTax = 15000.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else { fprintf(stderr, "Must be a positive number."); } //Error check for negative numbers.
}

int menuOptionT()
{
    printf("\nTax Calculator\n");

    double income;

    do {
        printf("\nMonthly Commission: $");
    } while (!readAndValidateIncome(&income));
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    //CHECK IF IT IS A NUMBER

    calculateTax(income);

    printf("Tax: $%8.2lf", tax);
    printf("\nNet Pay: $%8.2lf", taxedIncome);
}

int menuOptionM()
{
    printf("\nMonthly File Process\n");

    #define DIRECTORY "C:\\# School Units\\Introduction to Software Engineering (2015 S1)\\Assignment\\Text Files\\"

    FILE *infile;
    char fileName[512];
    char fullFileName[512];

    int dayNumber;
    char monthText[16];
    char firstName[32];
    char lastName[32];
    char planCode[8];
    double income;

    double totalIncome = 0.00;
    double totalNetIncome = 0.00;

    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("\nEnter Monthly File: ");
    scanf_s("%s", fileName, 120);

    strcpy_s(fullFileName, 512, DIRECTORY);
    strcat_s(fullFileName, 512, fileName);

    infile = fopen(fullFileName, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError Opening File >> %s \n\n", fullFileName);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSuccessfully Opened File >> %s \n\n", fullFileName);
    }

    while (6 == fscanf_s(infile, "%d %s %s %s %s %lf", &dayNumber, monthText, 16, firstName, 32, lastName, 32, planCode, 8, &income))
    {
        //calculateTax(totalIncome);

        //printf("Debug> %d:%s:%s:%s:%s:%8.2lf\n", dayNumber, monthText, firstName, lastName, planCode, income);

        totalNetIncome = totalNetIncome + income;
    }
    calculateTax(totalNetIncome);
    totalIncome = totalNetIncome;
    totalNetIncome = totalIncome - tax;

    printf("Pay slip for %s %s from file %s\n", firstName, lastName, fileName);
    printf("+-------------------------+\n");
    printf("| Commission : $ %8.2lf |\n", totalIncome);
    printf("| Tax        : $ %8.2lf |\n", tax);
    printf("|              ---------- |\n");
    printf("| Net Pay    : $ %8.2lf |\n", totalNetIncome);
    printf("+-------------------------+\n");

    printf("\nOFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'\n");
    printf("Please pay %s %s an amount of $%.2lf\n", firstName, lastName, totalNetIncome);
    printf("[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911");

    fclose(infile);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int menuOptionP()
{
    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CODE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}

int main()
{
    //Main menu variables.
    char menuChoice;

    //Do while loop for menu options.
    do
    {
        printf("\n\nOption | Action\n");
        printf("     Q | Quit\n");
        printf("     T | Tax Computation\n"); 
        printf("     M | Monthly File Process\n"); 
        printf("     P | Payroll File Process\n"); 
        printf("Select Option: ");
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        scanf("%c", &menuChoice);
        menuChoice = toupper(menuChoice); //Makes any input upper case.
        if (menuChoice == 'T') { menuOptionT(); } //Executes the menuOptionT function for tax computation.
        if (menuChoice == 'M') { menuOptionM(); } //Executes the menuOptionM function for monthly file process.
        if (menuChoice == 'P') { menuOptionP(); } //Executes the menuOptionP function for payroll file process.
    } while (menuChoice != 'Q'); //Quits the program.

    _getch;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to design data structures to store details for each employee. A common approach would be a `struct` for each employee and then a linked list or array of those structs.